# Why global is not working with def function please

Tags: python, function, global

`def global` is not working

```
output:NameError: name 'text2' is not defined
```

```
import tkinter as tk
from tkinter import *
from PIL import ImageTk, Image

def getentry():
    global entry
    global text2
    entry = sampiyon.get()
    dosya = open("deneme.txt","a")
    dosya.write(entry)
    dosya = open("sampiyon_listesi.txt","r",encoding="utf-8")
    liste = dosya.readline()
    global text2
    text2 = Label(root, text="Tekrar Deneyin")
    if liste == entry:
        text1 = Label(root, text="Tebrikler Doğru")
        text1.pack()
        text2.pack_forget()
    else:
        text2.pack()


root = Tk()


sampiyon = Entry(root)
print(text2)

root.mainloop()
```

Comment: `text2` will only be created when `getentry` is called. But `getentry` is not called.

Comment: Please trim your code to make it easier to find your problem. Follow these guidelines to create a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

## Add a `text2` variable in the global scope

You need to add this line in the global scope.

```py
text2 = None
```

Here is the code:

```py
from tkinter import *

text2 = None


def getentry():
    global entry
    entry = sampiyon.get()
    dosya = open("deneme.txt", "a")
    dosya.write(entry)
    dosya = open("sampiyon_listesi.txt", "r", encoding="utf-8")
    liste = dosya.readline()
    global text2
    text2 = Label(root, text="Tekrar Deneyin")
    if liste == entry:
        text1 = Label(root, text="Tebrikler Doğru")
        text1.pack()
        text2.pack_forget()
    else:
        text2.pack()


root = Tk()

sampiyon = Entry(root)
print(text2)

root.mainloop()
```

Result:

[image]